# Setting up CloudFront with SSL/TLS certificate and EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, certificate, amazon-cloudfront

Community.

I have a web page served by Apache running on a EC2 AWS instance. I am using AWS Certificate Manager with CloudFront to manage SSL/TLS in order to access the web page using HTTPS

**My environment:**

**Domain**: some.com.do

**AWS Certificate Alternate domain names**: some.com.do, *.some.com.do

**CloudFront Settings**

**Name**: some.cloudfront.net

**Domain names**: some.com.do, *.some.com.do

**Security policy**: TLSv1.2_2021

**Origin domain**: EC2 public DNS

**Origin Protocol**: HTTPS only

**Minimum origin SSL protocol**: TLSv1.2

**Viewer protocol policy**: Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

**Route 53 Settings**

some.com.do type A Simple Routing Alias Route to some.cloudfront.net

[www.some.com.do](http://www.some.com.do) type A Simple Routing Alias Route to some.com.do

The page does not load well when using https

And right now, I am getting the error:

502 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.

CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Comment: Can you please expand on "the web page doesn't load well". Do some resources not load? Is it slow? Something else? Please be precise, and if relevant include logs or other details.

Comment: To be precise, the web page shows as unsecured, I mean, it is not using https. If I choose  Origin Protocol: HTTP only, it loads unsecured but shows the web page correctly.

Comment: Tim, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help work out the problem. CloudFront can't contact the origin. Can you connect to your origin from your PC? Is there a firewall of some kind stopping CloudFront connecting (NACL, SG, instance)? The domain name of the origin typically needs to be different from the CloudFront domain name otherwise you can't specify what to connect to separately from CloudFront.

Comment: I can connect origin from my PC. I can connect via SSH, in the browser to view my web page (using public IP or public hostname). There is no firewall enabled in the OS. SG is configured to allow traffic for 80 and 443 ports. The domain name is different from the CloudFront domain name (it's a domain name given by AWS xyz.cloudfront.net)

Comment: That sounds ok. Unfortunately with the information provided there's nothing else I can say to help. I would work through the settings / problem to see what I find. If you can't work it out I suggest paying for AWS Support for a month as with your permission they can look at your account and tell you what's wrong.

Comment: But What info do you need?

Comment: I don't actually know. What you've said sounds fine. If it was me I would work through everything from first principles and work it out. I've been doing AWS for years but don't do much in this area, it's one of those things I could probably work out by poking around.

Comment: I see. Well, thanks for your time, Tim.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue when I'm trying to set up EC2 node at the backend for AWS Cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the misconfiguration of the behaviours of the distribution. Seems like CF did not pass all the headers to my EC2 backend node.